# authenticatedUser is null but principle is not null

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

Newbie to Grails security here. I am going through the documentation and tried this.
After successfully logging in, why is authenticated user is null even though principal is populated. Is there something else I need to do?

```
class SecureController {

 @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
 def userInfo(){
     if (isLoggedIn()){
      //authenticatedUser is null though user is authenticated.
      render authenticatedUser
      //render principal
    }
 }
}
```

From the documentation

**getAuthenticatedUser**

> Loads the user domain class instance from the database that corresponds to the currently 
>   authenticated user, or null if not authenticated. This is the
>   equivalent of adding a dependency injection for springSecurityService
>   and calling
>   PersonDomainClassName.get(springSecurityService.principal.id) (the
>   typical way that this is often done).

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the springSecurityService in the controller

```
class SecureController {

 def springSecurityService

 @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
 def userInfo(){
     if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()){
      //authenticatedUser is null though user is authenticated.
      render authenticatedUser
      //render principal
    }
 }
}
```

You could also use springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() to check whether you have a valid logged in user and render it. The [spring security core documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#springSecurityService) is pretty clear, check it out!

Comment: I don't think I need to inject springSecurityService unless I am using it directly in my code. isLoggedIn() is a convenience accessor method. But my question is, isLoggedIn works whether I inject it or not. Principal is populated too. It's the authenticated user that I am having issues with.